# Android not able to center text inside spinner using custom style

Tags: java, android, layout, styles, spinner

I have a SearchableSpinner and I want to display the text in the center of it

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
     
       <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_client"
                        style="@style/spinner_style_v2"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>


     </LinearLayout>
```

and here the custom style. I tried adding `<item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>` but it's not working also I've tried `<item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>`
to see if the text will move to the bottom a little bit but it's not moving.

```
<style name="spinner_style_v2">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/gradient_spinner</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">#DFFFFFFF</item>

</style>
```

Spinner adapter

```
try {
    if (clientList != null && clientList.size() > 0) {
        ArrayAdapter<Client> clientArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Client>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, clientList);
        clientArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        clientSpinner.setAdapter(clientArrayAdapter);
        clientSpinner.setTitle("Choose Client");
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.d(TAG, ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: do you want to center all of item horizontally in the list ?

Comment: can you share your spinner initialization code ?

Comment: horizontally and vertically like from (top - bottom - left - right).

Comment: in each row on the list ?

Comment: @ShayKin question is updated.I'm not able to add images but I want it to be like the third picture from this post https://www.android-examples.com/change-spinner-text-alignment-gravity-in-android-programmatically/

Comment: to center the Text for each line of your list you must create a custom layout and add it instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`

Comment: @ShayKin then what is the use of the custom spinner style?

Comment: @ShayKin I tried it. It's working post it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center item in your Spinner create a Custom layout and center **TextView** with  `android:gravity="center"` like the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
```

and in your java code use this layout as *@LayoutRes* in your Adapter :

```
ArrayAdapter<Client> clientArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Client>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.simple_text, clientList);
```